# Return type of resolve parameter is inferred as an object?

Tags: typescript

The following won't compile:

```
function P() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const stringValue:string = "...explicit string...";
      resolve(stringValue);
   });
}

async function f() {
  let s:string = "";
  await P().then((res) => { s = res; });
}
```

The error is at the statement `s = res`:

> [ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify return type.

```
function P(): Promise<string> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const stringValue:string = "...explicit string...";
      resolve(stringValue);
   });
}

async function f() {
  let s:string = "";
  await P().then((res) => { s = res; });
}
```

TypeScript assumes return type of P is `Promise<{}>` when you do not specify return type. You can check it at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html , type your code on left side and put mouse on `P().then(` , you will see that typescript assumes return type as `Promise<{}>`.

Comment: Or just specify generic type parameter when you create a promise: `return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => { ...` cc @Old Geezer